# Azure - App Service - Mobile App Quickstart - Connect a Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, mobile, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

### **Configured Azure SQL database not showing in Azure App Services / Quickstart.**

I've created an Azure SQL DB with a basic table and setup a new Azure App service with the connection set to the created DB, both under data connections and as a connection string under configuration.

I have a problem when using the deployment/quickstart under the app service menu.

The problem I have is:

Option 1. Connect to database - Does not show my database, I just get a link saying "Click here to learn how to connect a database" - Following the link just states that data connections are being superceeded by manual connection strings and gives instructions on how to add a connection string (which I have done).

[image]

I've used the troubleshooting tools to check the connection string and it all works fine, as does an external connection to the SQL database from an editor.

[image]

So without the database connected to the app service, when I download the inital source code project, there is obviously no connection to the database.  So I'm kind of stuck.

I've tried re-creating, restarting etc.  Same thing evey time.

When loading the quickstart options menu, Option 1 should give me a list of available databases based on the appservice data connections/connection strings and then allow me to select one (image below).  But instead I just get: "Click here to learn how to connect a database"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I just created the to do list application. You just proceed with steps 2 and 3. Dont worry about the green tick you are hoping to see for step 1.

Just follow the steps in the link below. Very easy:
https://alligatortek.com/blog/developing-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-and-azure/

See my data in the SQL database viewed using VS 2017:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  you're correct.  It does all work when the app is compiled and run.  The quickstart interface is just a little miseading.